# Can not retrieve sql server routine return parameter schema information

Tags: sql-server, bcs, external-content-type, external-list, sql

I am trying to create an external content type on Sql stored procedure in sharepoint 2013 and getting the following error:

***Invalid Object Name '#...' .Can not retrieve sql server routine return parameter schema information***